# Sorting array based on date/time

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array based on date/time, however it doesn't seem to be working correctly when I do a print_r. My best guess is that the time I provided to strtotime() is not in the correct format however the date and time formats are both listed, but separately in the php manual and no errors are thrown.

The format I use is unclear in the code so here it is: yyyy-mm-dd hhmm (24h with no colon GMT)

Here is the code:

```
function dateSort($a, $b){
    $d1 = strtotime($a['date'].' '.$a['startTime']);
    $d2 = strtotime($b['date'].' '.$a['startTime']);
    return $d1 - $d2;
}    
usort($events, 'dateSort');
print_r($events);
```

Comment: Check the values of `$d1` and `$d2` before doing `return` and see if they are what you are expecting. Maybe give some example values for the array items so we produce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IVAO.
You had a typo in third line of snippet. Second line refers to `$a`, but in 3rd you mix both `$b` and `$a` :).

Also, I think, you needn't use strtotime at all. Look into snippet:

```
<?php

function dateSort($a, $b)
{
    $d1 = floatval(str_replace('-', '', $a['date']) . " $a[startTime]");
    $d2 = floatval(str_replace('-', '', $b['date']) . " $b[startTime]");
    return $d1 - $d2;
}

$events = [
    ['date' => '2015-05-01', 'startTime' => '2300', 'value' => 'Event 1'],
    ['date' => '2012-05-01', 'startTime' => '1430', 'value' => 'Event 2'],
    ['date' => '2011-09-17', 'startTime' => '1021', 'value' => 'Event 3'],
    ['date' => '2001-01-22', 'startTime' => '0959', 'value' => 'Event 4'],
    ['date' => '1999-02-05', 'startTime' => '1740', 'value' => 'Event 5'],
];

usort($events, 'dateSort');
echo '<pre>' . print_r($events, 1) . '</pre>';
```

[And click to codepad.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PWCvMl)

Answer (score 1):

From Php manual, you can try to update your dateSort() function

```
function dateSort($a, $b){
    $d1 = strtotime($a['date'].' '.$a['startTime']);
    $d2 = strtotime($b['date'].' '.$a['startTime']);
    return ($d1 < $d2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Suggest you to give us some of your output, easier to take it from there.

Comment: I tryed pasting in your code above and it doesn't change the sort order at all. Upon further investigation I believe it is the time that is the issue in mine. You can see a demo of the array after it is sorted here: http://www.aaron-schpitzer.ca/en/events

Comment: It almost looks like the time is getting ignored completely, the ids are in order on the same date

Comment: @IVAOCA-WM updated the code. The original code was from PHP manual and I suggested you to update your code yourself...